# The comboBox inside the window is not getting populated. But outside it works fine (ExtJS)

Tags: extjs

I have created a comboBox of states. When rendering it simply to the body it gets populated but when I put it in a window it shows no values. And also is there way that I can make the comboBox inside the window a multiSelect one

multiSelectCombo.js:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    // The data store containing the list of states
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data: [{
            name: 'ALABAMA',
            abbreviation: 'AL'
        }, {
            name: 'ALASKA',
            abbreviation: 'AK'
        }, {
            name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA',
            abbreviation: 'AS'
        }, {
            name: 'ARIZONA',
            abbreviation: 'AZ'
        }, {
            name: 'ARKANSAS',
            abbreviation: 'AR'
        }, {
            name: 'CALIFORNIA',
            abbreviation: 'CA'
        }, {
            name: 'COLORADO',
            abbreviation: 'CO'
        }, {
            name: 'CONNECTICUT',
            abbreviation: 'CT'
        }, {
            name: 'DELAWARE',
            abbreviation: 'DE'
        }, {
            name: 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA',
            abbreviation: 'DC'
        }, {
            name: 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA',
            abbreviation: 'FM'
        }, {
            name: 'FLORIDA',
            abbreviation: 'FL'
        }, {
            name: 'GEORGIA',
            abbreviation: 'GA'
        }, {
            name: 'GUAM',
            abbreviation: 'GU'
        }, {
            name: 'HAWAII',
            abbreviation: 'HI'
        }, {
            name: 'IDAHO',
            abbreviation: 'ID'
        }, {
            name: 'ILLINOIS',
            abbreviation: 'IL'
        }, {
            name: 'INDIANA',
            abbreviation: 'IN'
        }, {
            name: 'IOWA',
            abbreviation: 'IA'
        }, {
            name: 'KANSAS',
            abbreviation: 'KS'
        }, {
            name: 'KENTUCKY',
            abbreviation: 'KY'
        }, {
            name: 'LOUISIANA',
            abbreviation: 'LA'
        }, {
            name: 'MAINE',
            abbreviation: 'ME'
        }, {
            name: 'MARSHALL ISLANDS',
            abbreviation: 'MH'
        }, {
            name: 'MARYLAND',
            abbreviation: 'MD'
        }, {
            name: 'MASSACHUSETTS',
            abbreviation: 'MA'
        }, {
            name: 'MICHIGAN',
            abbreviation: 'MI'
        }, {
            name: 'MINNESOTA',
            abbreviation: 'MN'
        }, {
            name: 'MISSISSIPPI',
            abbreviation: 'MS'
        }, {
            name: 'MISSOURI',
            abbreviation: 'MO'
        }, {
            name: 'MONTANA',
            abbreviation: 'MT'
        }, {
            name: 'NEBRASKA',
            abbreviation: 'NE'
        }, {
            name: 'NEVADA',
            abbreviation: 'NV'
        }, {
            name: 'NEW HAMPSHIRE',
            abbreviation: 'NH'
        }, {
            name: 'NEW JERSEY',
            abbreviation: 'NJ'
        }, {
            name: 'NEW MEXICO',
            abbreviation: 'NM'
        }, {
            name: 'NEW YORK',
            abbreviation: 'NY'
        }, {
            name: 'NORTH CAROLINA',
            abbreviation: 'NC'
        }, {
            name: 'NORTH DAKOTA',
            abbreviation: 'ND'
        }, {
            name: 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS',
            abbreviation: 'MP'
        }, {
            name: 'OHIO',
            abbreviation: 'OH'
        }, {
            name: 'OKLAHOMA',
            abbreviation: 'OK'
        }, {
            name: 'OREGON',
            abbreviation: 'OR'
        }, {
            name: 'PALAU',
            abbreviation: 'PW'
        }, {
            name: 'PENNSYLVANIA',
            abbreviation: 'PA'
        }, {
            name: 'PUERTO RICO',
            abbreviation: 'PR'
        }, {
            name: 'RHODE ISLAND',
            abbreviation: 'RI'
        }, {
            name: 'SOUTH CAROLINA',
            abbreviation: 'SC'
        }, {
            name: 'SOUTH DAKOTA',
            abbreviation: 'SD'
        }, {
            name: 'TENNESSEE',
            abbreviation: 'TN'
        }, {
            name: 'TEXAS',
            abbreviation: 'TX'
        }, {
            name: 'UTAH',
            abbreviation: 'UT'
        }, {
            name: 'VERMONT',
            abbreviation: 'VT'
        }, {
            name: 'VIRGIN ISLANDS',
            abbreviation: 'VI'
        }, {
            name: 'VIRGINIA',
            abbreviation: 'VA'
        }, {
            name: 'WASHINGTON',
            abbreviation: 'WA'
        }, {
            name: 'WEST VIRGINIA',
            abbreviation: 'WV'
        }, {
            name: 'WISCONSIN',
            abbreviation: 'WI'
        }, {
            name: 'WYOMING',
            abbreviation: 'WY'
        }]
    });

    // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        labelAlign: 'top',
        labelPad: 10,
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbreviation',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        multiSelect: true,
        width: 400,
        displayTpl: '<tpl for=".">' +
            '{name}' +
            '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">, </tpl>' +
            '</tpl>',
        listConfig: {
            itemTpl: '{name} <div class="chkbox"></div>'
        },
        listeners: {
            select: function (combo, records) {
                console.log(records.length);   
            }
        }
    });
    var myWin=new Ext.Window({
        title:'Please select your locations',
       heihgt:220,
       width:230,
       bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
       layout:'form',
       labelWidth:50,
       defaultType:'field',
       items:[
       {
           xtype:'combo',
           fieldlabel:'Location',
           width:120,
           store:states
       }]
   });
   myWin.show();

});
```

HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="multiSelectCombo.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI your store fields configuration is incorrect, it should be 'abbreviation' instead of 'abbr'. Not the source of your problem though, newmount's answer bellow is correct.

Comment: @rixo Hey thanks a lot sir. Appreciate it, upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these three configs needs to be set for the combo inside window

```
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'abbreviation',
multiSelect: true,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it soon. Upvoted. I will mark it as an answer once i try it out.